# different theme output for desktop and mobile

Tags: css

I have an RTL theme for my wordpress site eblog.elektrojo.com which uses the Arabic language. A part of the website is a store using woocommerce and since the items descriptions and details are English and cant be easily translated to Arabic I edited the template for sections in the product page only to be LTR.

The issue is: mobile phones do not show the changes for both mobile and desktop version while on a laptop it's perfect as I want.

How to inspect elements for the mobile view? (A Note: when using chrome mobile view the pages are as I want )

Store page: eblog.elektrojo.com/shop

[image: Mobile phone, not showing the changes]

[image: desktop chrome shows the changes]

Finally I am not a wordpress developer, just a normal user

Comment: Did you tried clearing cache on mobile device's browser? or using different mobile browser? (like firefox for android)

Comment: I tried diffrent mobiles, but not diffrent browsers.

Comment: would you be kind enough to elaborate on the result?

Comment: I am just confirming the result I got before, diffrent mobile phones using chrome  do not show the changes.

Comment: this probably caused by some cache. could be in browser cache. did you tried with incognito?

Comment: I just downloaded firefox and it works fine, but chrome is not even the two mobiles are in two diffrent countries and using the webpage for the first time.

Comment: if chrome in desktop shows page fine, then it should in the mobile because both uses same renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Chrome Dev tools - it has device screen size simulators built-in and many other useful tools https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

And to see any changes try clearing the browser cache:

- Open Dev Tools by pressing: F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I (or on Mac:
  Opt+Cmd+I)
- Now by just leaving dev tools open, right-click or click and hold the
  reload button next to the address bar. Now a somewhat 'hidden menu'
  opens.
- Choose: "Empty Cache and Hard Reload"